# How to subset the dataset (data.frame) based on Date (08-10-2014)?

Tags: r

I have two data.frames `A`, `B`, sharing the two similar variables (`ID` and `Date`). I want to find the `ID` with the `Date` earlier than `01-01-2015` from both datasets. 
I try to use `subset(A, Date < "01-01-2015")`, however, there's always problem about `Date`. I also try to use `as.Date` to solve the problem. BUT it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @TuoLi514!  Could you edit your question to include a [small example that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  It is also helpful if you can show the text of the error itself.

Comment: Try this: `subset(A, as.date(A$Date < "01-01-2015")`

Comment: @user2923027 - you have to specify a format to that `as.Date` - your code will not work on `m-d-Y` by default. R looks for `Y-m-d` rather than the nonsensical US sorting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Using as.Date and specifying the date format you're giving it should help.

```
date = c("12-30-2014", "07-01-2014", "08-01-2014", "12-02-2015")
date = as.Date(date, "%m-%d-%Y")
date < as.Date("01-01-2015", "%m-%d-%Y")
```

gives:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for editing above, @thelatemail. This was my first answer, and I'm trying to learn the ropes of replying decently.